# programmatically choose an attribute of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

When I call this function with `date_narrow(pdb, "datepub", "1980", "2000")` I expected the returned count to be 2, and pdb[0].selected to be set to false. Instead, my debugger shows that arr[k].dfield is always undefined, whereas I want it to be pdb[k].datepub. That is, I am trying to select the attribute of the object arr[k] at runtime. Any suggestion on how to do this correctly?

```
var date_narrow = function (arr, dfield, earlier_date, later_date) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k].selected) {
            // following are string comparisons
            if ((arr[k].dfield < earlier_date) || (arr[k].dfield > later_date)) {
                arr[k].selected = false;
            } else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count);
};

pdb = [{
    datepub: "2012",
    selected: true
}, {
    datepub: "1999",
    selected: true
}, {
    datepub: "1980",
    selected: true
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the array syntax (`obj[...]`) also works for accessing an object's properties by name:

```
var date_narrow = function (arr, dfield, earlier_date, later_date) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k].selected) {
            // following are string comparisons
            if ((arr[k][dfield] < earlier_date) || (arr[k][dfield] > later_date)) {
                arr[k].selected = false;
            } else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count);
};
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzh2h/)

Comment: That works, thanks. I thought that as long as dfield is a string that is a legal javascript name and not a reserved word, arr[k].dfield means the same as arr[k][dfield], and is easier to read. Apparently they don't mean the same. Can you explain?

Comment: @user1416227 They mean different things. `x.prop` means 'get the property named `prop` from object `x`', while `x[prop]` means 'get the value of the variable named `prop` and then get the property of object `x` which has that name (or array index)'.